# parametric integration and numeric plotting of a 2D function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am going to devise a 2D function as a probability density function, is which a function of two variables, i.e. `f = f(x,n)`. Then, as the target is plotting the probability variation, the integration in related to parameter `x` should be taken into account. The `t` parameter is the variable planned to be the upper bound of the integration. It is suffice to say that `n` is the other tuning factor. Finally, with due attention to the considered `meshgrid`, the probability surface is supposed to be drawn.

My option for the integration process is the symbolic `int` function. But there is an error: `Error using mupadmex`

Here is my code:

```
clear;

syms x;
syms n;
syms t;

sigma = 1;
mu = 0;

[t,n] = meshgrid(0:0.01:20, 1:1:100);

f = (n./(2*sigma*sqrt(pi))).*exp(-((n.*x)./(2.*sigma)).^2);

ff = int(f, x, -inf, t);

mesh(n,t,ff);
```

And the error trace:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: The argument is invalid. [Dom::Interval::new]

Error in sym/int (line 153)
   rSym = mupadmex('symobj::intdef',f.s,x.s,a.s,b.s,options);

Error in field (line 14)
ff = int(f, x, -inf, t);
```

Would you please helping me to overcome this tie?!

PS. I know that there are some ideas to do this stuff more numerically by `integral` function, but I am prone to handle this case by `int` function, if it is possible. Because this code should be used as a service by the other snippets and the generated `ff` parameter is completely deserving, however it won't be a closed form function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are trying to evaluate the function `f(x,n)` 2000000 times for different x and and upper limit of the integral? Each `f(x,ni)` has an specific upper imit `ti`? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: You're completely on board!... The applied range for `t` is considerably desired for the required resolution and sweeping the final plot. Though, it is not the problem!

Comment: @Ordenador It seems you want to integrate a Gaussian function. Why not just use the `erfc` or `normcdf` functions?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Because I've caught some degrees of freedom for next computational steps by this approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed several details in your code, Ill try to explain all of them.

1. No need of defining symbolic variables that are not going to be symbolic.

code:

```
clear;

syms x;

sigma = 1;
mu = 0; % This is never used!
```

2. You want to integrate a function f(n,x) dx for different n. If you create a meshgrid of n (instead of a vector), you will have tons of repeated f(ni,x) that you are not going to use.

Just do:

```
t=(0:1:20);

n=(1:10:100);
% are you sure you dont want ((n.*x)-mu) here?
f = (n./(2*sigma*sqrt(pi))).*exp(-((n.*x)./(2.*sigma)).^2);
```

3. `int` does not accept a mesh of symbolic functions! (or I haven't managed to make it work...).

So put a couple of for's there!

```
for ii=1:length(n)
    for jj=1:length(t)
        ff(ii,jj) = int(f(ii), x, -inf, t(jj));
    end
end
```

4. Now we DO want a meshgrid for the plot!

Like this:

```
[t,n] = meshgrid(t, n);
```

5. And you want to plot the numerical value, so use `double()` to convert from symbolic to numerical:

plot!:

```
mesh(n,t,double(ff));
```

Result (with low amount of points due to the obvious computational effort needed)

[image]

Comment: How is your evaluation regarding such two `for` loops in view of the performance, in comparison with passing `meshgrid` into the `int` function, within one shot?... Your idea works,,, But it is considerably verbose and probably inefficient...

Comment: @Ordenador I did it with for loops because I cant find a way of doing it without. I tried your direct method (with meshgrid) and I am not sure how it compares to the for loops, but it was very slow, and I just got a meshgrid of 1s. AFAIK, the error you are getting is exactly for that, you cannot give the `int` fuction a meshgrid for integral limits.

Comment: @Ordenador Hope someone can give a better answer, but I dont think you will be able to get over the fact that int does not accept mesh limmits!